# No module named 'requests' when there most definitely is

Tags: python, windows, cmd, python-requests

I use cmd prompt to open a py file.

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'

I run Python in the terminal. run help('modules'). Look at the list of modules. I see that requests is definitely there.

I quit python and try to run the file again.

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'

Any ideas?

Comment: Please post the content of the file you are running.

Comment: just check if you are using same python env in bot cases or not

Comment: Does "requests" module show up if run `pip list` ?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: you may have two Pythons installed and you may install module in one Python and run code with other Python. OR you may use virtual environments and check modules outside environment and run code inside environment. Maybe run in file `import sys ; print( sys.executable )` to get `/full/path/to/python` and later use `/full/path/to/python -m pip install requests` to install module with this Python.